# Is there an online calculator in which you can type a number and have it tell you if it could be a Lychrel number or not?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, math-software, palindrome

Say you type $7326$ into it, it runs a few calculations and tells you it reaches $99099$ in three iterations. But if you type in a number like $887$, it runs a reasonable number of iterations (say, twenty) and tells you it doesn't reach a palindrome in that number of iterations.

In response to another question, I tried to determine if $9988$ is a Lychrel number. After ten iterations on a general purpose calculator, I could not find a palindrome, but I could have made a mistake somewhere. I also tried asking Google "Is $9988$ a Lychrel number?" The results were unenlightening.

Comment: It's unknown, as well as all the other terms in http://oeis.org/A023108 and many more.

Comment: But surely there is some tool that can reliably tell me that it doesn't reach a palindrome in some small number of iterations, some tool that's not going to inadvertently mix up the digits (e.g., type 68779 instead of 86779).

Comment: One can write a short program to do this in any high-level language, e.g. Python.

Comment: If I really wanted to, I could do it in Javascript. But wouldn't I be reinventing the wheel? Hasn't anyone done this and made it available online?

Comment: @RobertSoupe If a Google search didn't turn anything up, then anyone who wrote one likely kept it to themselves. You may have to write it in Javascript.

Comment: $9988 = 1997+7991$ and $1997$ appears on the list [OEIS A023108](http://oeis.org/A023108).

Comment: @vadim123 See [Code Review question 44272](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44272/9357) for a Python implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

> http://js.do/daveyp225/lychrel

I tried to make the code semi-readable, just set $N$ to the number of iterations you wish to go before rejecting; by default I have it set to $25$. The value of the iterations rises very quickly. As a result, too high of iterations are not supported by javascript. Without a moderate amount of additional work (e.g. custom classes) this is roughly the best javascript can do. If there are any obvious improvements I can make let me know.

**Edit:** I had to make a correction, as for some reason a few *select* powers of ten do not behave well with javascript. For example:

`Math.log(1000)/Math.log(10)`  Returns `2.9999999999999996` rather than `3`.

This correction will not affect any "ordinary" inputs. I added $10^{-14}$ to the logarithm before taking the floor of the input.